# Problem with Installing Ubuntu ; stays on the loading screen

Tags: installation, boot

I have a problem when I boot from the CD, it **stays** on the *loading screen*.

so what must I do ?

> Details;

- *Version: 13*.__

Comment: Have you tried using ACPI=off, nolacpi, etc? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If your computer has an ATI, I had a similar problem. Try choosing "other boot options" in the boot menu (I think it was linked to F6) and choose "nomodeset".